# Unable to execute dbachecks command

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools, dbachecks

i installed dbachecks module in a server. but when i am trying to execute get-dbccheck, it is throwing the below error

```
Populating RepositorySourceLocation property for module Pester.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\5.0.4\Pester.psm1'.
[18:59:41][dbachecks.psm1] Failed to import suitable version - Do you have Version 4* installed ?
Get-DbcCheck : The 'Get-DbcCheck' command was found in the module 'dbachecks', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module dbachecks'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-DbcCheck
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-DbcCheck:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

I have updated the pester and psframework modules to the latest, still i am unable to execute the commands.

Can someone help me in this.?

Comment: There is a [Wiki](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbachecks/wiki) page on Github, maybe you can post your Issue there.

Comment: thanks Mcnets. I have posted the question there...